# How to use ActiveRecord's "where" to search an array in the database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

for example, here is my entry

```
Entry id: 3, entry_text: "test", tags: ["3817483"], created_at: "2014-12-16 08:29:24", updated_at: "2014-12-16 08:29:24", user_id: 1
```

I am trying to get this entry using ActiveRecord's where

but apparently `Entry.where("tags =?","3817483")` will not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Better question is, why is your database not normalised? `tags` should be its own table, with `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with your entries. Or you could use `acts-as-taggable` or `acts-as-taggable-on` gems, or similar, to do it for you. Your tag list should *not* be saved as a literal list.

Comment: Almost 100% agree with amadan except use `has_many: :through`

Comment: What database are you using? If this is a new project I recommend normalizing tags. If this is an established project with performance constraints sometime de-normalizing data like tags is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below

```
Entry.where('tags LIKE ?',"%3817483%").all
```